# Angular JS TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined on Route

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm in the process of learning a bit of AngularJS and I've hit a stumbling block. I can retrieve my jSON and feed it into the frontend, but my problem is coming when I'm going to a new view. My ID is not coming in correctly. Basically if click on my item that has a id 1 its displaying id 14. Or I get TypeError: Cannot read property '14' of undefined

Any ideas would be really helpful.

jSON

```
[
    {
        "id": 14,
        "title": "new post",
        "excerpt": "EXCERPT",
        "content": "ushajsd"
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "title": "last post",
        "excerpt": "test",
        "content": "test"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "middle post",
        "excerpt": "contents to post",
        "content": "contents to post"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Hello world!",
        "excerpt": "Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start blogging!",
        "content": "Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start blogging!"
    }
]
```

AngularJS

```
//Create main module
var module = angular.module('module', [''])

//Services

module.factory('posts', function($http) {
  return {
      getAsync: function(callback) {
          $http.get('/wp-content/themes/ajax/ajax.php').success(callback);
      }
  };
});

// Set up our mappings between URLs, templates, and controllers
function caseStudyConfig($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when('/casestudy/:id', {
      controller: caseCtrl,
      templateUrl: '/wp-content/themes/templates/casestudy.php'
    }).
    otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
}

// Set up our route so the service can find it
module.config(caseStudyConfig);

//Controllers
function homeCtrl (posts, $scope) {
  posts.getAsync(function(data) {
       $scope.content = data;
  });
}

function caseCtrl (posts, $scope, $routeParams) {
  posts.getAsync(function(data) {
       $scope.content = data[$routeParams.id];
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data property in your `getAsync` callback is a representation of the JSON you've posted, I think it's because you're attempting to access the object by it's position in the array and not by its id property. If you're using [underscore / lodash](http://underscorejs.org/), you could fix this easily like so:

```
function caseCtrl (posts, $scope, $routeParams) {
  posts.getAsync(function(data) {
       // Find the object with id which matches id in route params
       $scope.content = _.findWhere(data, { id: $routeParams.id });
  });
}
```

Or you could write your own loop to retrieve the correct object from the collection:

```
function caseCtrl (posts, $scope, $routeParams) {
  posts.getAsync(function(data) {
       $scope.content = getObjectById(data, $routeParams.id);
  });

  function getObjectById(collection, id) {
    for (var i = 0, obj; i < collection.length; i ++) {
        obj = collection[i];
        if (obj.id === id) {
            return obj;
        }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Maybe I need to change how I get my data. As I dont want to start bringing in another library. When I expect this is something easy to do in angularJS on its own.

Comment: Updated my answer to show you how you could loop over the collection yourself to find the correct object. underscore is really, really handy for this sort of thing however, so probably worth bearing in mind.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a whirl. I will keep underscore in mind - bit of a noob at the moment so learning one thing is enough for the moment.

Comment: Let me know how you get on.